Detect scale reference line coordinates in Python
I’m trying to process a bunch of object images.
Each of them has a scale reference depicted in form of line.
(via. as shown in the attached image)
Position and size of lines can vary.
I would like to find any suitable Python library or suitable alternative to get line edge coordinates
(e.g. [10,20] for line's left edge and [10,120] for right one)
At this point I'm already using OpenCV, Tensorflow and Pytesseract in my script.
Alternatively would be considerable to crop all image outside scale-factor box, to later process it's contents.
Would appreciate any suggestions.


This is not hard.  Take a starting point on the bottom row, about 90% of the way across.  Now, move up until you find white.  Then move up until you find black.  Now you have the line.  You can move left and right to find the ends.  Or, start at the bottom right and move diagonally up and left.

This implements what I talk about above.  Start from the lower right corner, scoot up to find white.  Scoot a little bit more, than go up to find black.  Now go left and right to find the ends.
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('../Downloads/image1.png')
pix = np.array(img.getdata()).reshape(img.size[1], img.size[0], 3)

h,w,d = pix.shape

# Search from the bottom right corner for white.

x = w-1
y = h-1
while np.any(pix[y][x] != (255,255,255)):
    x -= 1
    y -= 1
print('white found at',x,y)

# Scoot another 12 pixels.

x -= 12
y -= 12

# Go up to find black.

while np.any(pix[y][x]):
    y -= 1
print('black found at',x,y)

x0 = x
y -= 1

# Go left to find the start.

while np.all(pix[y][x] == (0,0,0)):
    x -= 1

left_edge = (x,y)

x = x0
while np.all(pix[y][x] == (0,0,0)):
    x += 1

right_edge = (x,y)

print("Left",left_edge,"right",right_edge)

Output:
white found at 895 553
black found at 883 502
Left (667, 501) right (889, 501)

Note that these must be computer generated images, as opposed to scans or photos, because the whites are pure white and the blacks are pure black.  It's important to know that.  You could DO this task by checking for "close to white" and "close to black", but it's not needed here.

Thanks!
Just have posted a solution I ended up with.

Thanks Tim for helping out!
I've ended up reiterating your solution to something similar.
Just in case anyone would be interested, I will also post it here.
(Ended up accessing an ndarray image by [Y, X] coordinates.
Did use PixelLens Pycharm extension to debug how image arrays look like)
The code:
def find_scale_box_edges(image: np.ndarray):
    step = 5

    def find_last_black_pixel(image: np.ndarray, start, step):
        _x = start[0]
        _y = start[1]
        if (image[_y, _x][:3] != [0,0,0]).all():
            raise Exception

        while _x > 0 and _x < image.shape[1]:
            while _y > 0 and _y < image.shape[0]:
                if (image[_y + step[1], _x + step[0]][:3] != [0,0,0]).any():
                    return [_x, _y]
                else:
                    _x = _x + step[0]
                    _y = _y + step[1]

        raise Exception

    for x in range(image.shape[1]-step-1, step, -50):
        for y in range(image.shape[0]):
            if (image[y, x][:3] == [0, 0, 0]).any():

                # check N horizontal nearby pixels to see if its truly a line.
                upper_border_test = image[y:y+2, x-step:x+step][:,:,:3]
                if (upper_border_test[:, 0] == [[0, 0, 0], [255, 255, 255]]).all():
                    top_left_corner = find_last_black_pixel(image, [x,y], [-1, 0])
                    top_right = find_last_black_pixel(image, [x, y], [1, 0])
                    bottom_right_corner = find_last_black_pixel(image, top_right, [0, 1])

                    # scale_box_image = image[top_left_corner[1]:bottom_right_corner[1],
                    #                   top_left_corner[0]:bottom_right_corner[0]]

                    return [top_left_corner, bottom_right_corner]
    return [None, None]

Result:

